How can I access the algorithm used in the Ant Design theme within a child component?
I am using Ant Design's ConfigProvider to apply theming in my React application. I want to access the algorithm (e.g., darkAlgorithm) used in the parent ConfigProvider within a child component to change its state dynamically
Here's my code:
<ConfigProvider theme={{ algorithm: theme.defaultAlgorithm }}>
    <ConfigProvider theme={{ algorithm: theme.darkAlgorithm }}>
        {children} // header I need the algorithm that used 
    </ConfigProvider>
</ConfigProvider>


How can I access the algorithm used in the parent ConfigProvider within a child component like Header? Is there a way to get this information using hooks or any other method?
